# The host cannot access the web service in the virtual machine

Tags: rust, vmware, rust-web3

I tried to access the web service in the virtual machine from the local host, but failed.

All ports are open, and the host and virtual machine firewalls are off, but it still doesn't work
virtual machine is archlinux, host is win10. here is code:

```
use std::net::TcpListener;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        println!("Connection established!");
    }
}
```

Comment: A socket bound to `127.0.0.1` will only listen to connections from that same machine, the VM is not the same machine as the host in that sense. Use `0.0.0.0` to listen for any incoming connection.